# Umbraco 7: Could not load type Umbraco.Web.UmbracoApplication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

1. Created an ASP.NET empty web application in Visual Studio
2. Installed Umbraco 7.1.5 via NuGet Package Manager
3. When asked to overwrite the web.config file, typed Y(Yes)
4. Built the project
5. F5

When I run the project I get the following error in Chrome:

[image: Could not load type Umbraco.Web.UmbracoApplication]

How can I solve this problem and get to the installation page?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I also encountered same problem few days ago..i solved that...Just change the name of  MVC project from **'Umbraco'** to something else and then it will work fine..

Comment: Thank you for this answer - I didn't even think about that!

Comment: @Kartikeya the name of my Umbraco website is not "Umbraco" - so how can i fix my issue? And how do you change the name of the MVC Project?

Comment: This answer (and the question) still applies - for Umbraco 7.7.2.

Comment: Still works today on v7.7.2 Visual Studio 2017 Community with ReSharper Ultimate. Rather than renaming project i just created a new one as I was following this guide https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/getting-started/setup/install/install-umbraco-with-nuget and installing from nuget.

Answer (score 1):

The solution, when I encountered it after installing Umbraco 7.2.12 into an existing but empty project, was to change the assembly name and default namespace from "Umbraco" to the name of the (startup-)project eg. "Website".

In Visual Studio 2017 (applies to many other versions of VS), you can do it like this:

1. Select your project
2. Select Properties
3. Select tab Application
4. Change Assembly name and Default namespace
5. Save ... and wait
6. Run