# Umbraco: Could not load type 'Umbraco.Web.UmbracoApplication'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, umbraco

I've downloaded Umbraco, connected to a database and installed a sample site but when I try to run in Visual Studio, I get this error:

Could not load type 'Umbraco.Web.UmbracoApplication'.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a missing reference. Without more information to go on, it's impossible to answer. Please update with more information.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Umbraco 7: Could not load type Umbraco.Web.UmbracoApplication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25461798/umbraco-7-could-not-load-type-umbraco-web-umbracoapplication)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually follow this guide to get Umbraco up and running with Visual Studio: [Setting up Umbraco 7 in Visual Studio 2013 for MVC 4 development](http://www.systenics.com/blog/setting-up-umbraco-7-in-visual-studio-2013-for-mvc-4-development/)

Answer (score 0):

You are possibly missing a reference. Also - I found this happens in my version 7.2.4 too.

Check that the install completes - especially if you installed with NuGet. Sometimes powershell doesn't work and the installation is not completed. Look for yellow text during installation. If this fails, try an older version.